Number of solutions for $N$-variable diophantine equation asserts this polynomial form---Polya Analysis


Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_l$ be positive integers without a common factor different from $1$ and $A_n$ be the number of non-negative solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^la_ix_i=n$$\cdots\cdots$




We suppose more: we assume $a_i$ coprime with $a_j$ whenever $i\ne j$



Then we can assert more:
$$A_n=P(n)+Q_n,$$
where $P(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients of degree $l-1$ and the sequence $ Q_n$ is periodic with period $\prod_{i=1}^l a_i$.

I don't know how to prove this.
Though Polya's Problems and Theorems in Analysis comes with a solution on the back, but I am still bewildered after looking at it:

Helps are welcomed.

Hi Owen,please reply
